# how to define an array with fractional index number

Tags: matlab

Like suppose that I need to create a function named `pressure` denoted by `p` (a 2-D matrix) which depends on 2 variables `r` and `z`.

`u`, `v`, `w` are linear matrices which also depend on 2 variables `r` and `z`.

`r` and `z` are linear matrix defined below take `i={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}`

```
r(i)=i/10
z(i)=i/10
u(i) = 2*r(i) + 3*z(i)
v(i) = 8*r(i) + 4*z(i)
w(i) = 3*r(i) + 2*z(i)
p = p(r,z) %, which is given as,
p(r(i),z(j)) = 2*v(i) - 4*u(i) + w(j)
```

Now suppose the value of `p` at a given location `(r,z)` say `(0.4,0.8)` is needed, I want that if I give the input `p(0.4,0.8)`, I get the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case the easiest way is to convert the fractional numbers to integers by multiplying by 10.

This way the location (r,z) = (0.4, 0.8) will become (4,8).

If you don't want to remember every time to provide the locations multiplied by 10, just create a function that will do it for you, so you can call the function with the fractional location.

If your matrices are **linear**, you will always find a multiplying factor to get rid of the fractional coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you mean here, but if your matrix is only defined in the indices you give (i.e. you only want to draw values from the fixed set of indices you defined), then this should do it:

```
% the query indices
r_i = 0.4; 
z_i = 0.8;

value = p(r_i*10,z_i*10);
```

if you want to look at values **between** the ones you defined, you need to look at interpolation:

```
% the query indices
r_i = 0.46; 
z_i = 0.84;

value = interp2(r,z, p, r_i, z_i);
```

(I may have gotten `r` and `z` in that last function in the wrong order, try it out).

Comment: This is not what the OP wants. He has a formula to calculate things, he wants, as his title says a *fractional index number*. This has nothing to do with interpolation.

Comment: Maybe you're right, but I didn't quite understand that from the way he asked. Anyways, pressure is a continuous phenomenon, maybe he might find it useful to look at values in between the fixed indices.